# Unable to send email through Python from Gmail on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, smtp, digital-ocean

I am running a DigitalOcean server on Ubuntu 20 and trying to send a notification email. The code runs fine on windows where I log in manually through the browser into the gmail account. On Ubuntu however I get the 534 authentification error. The problem is Google doesn't support non-javascript browsers so I cannot login through any of the command line ones like Lynx or Links/Links2.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_mail.py", line 35, in <module>
    server.login(sender_email,password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 743, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 732, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 655, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu\n5.7.14 aRDSZeqgJKpUYAv2MTRm76Oo727636gw5NP42UvNlPQh0VEh8P07whxbnBOiG2MTq7HZ3\n5.7.14 dBDFINUjU1AZM8pqPiwKjer9l9JNmPdYv0DPu_aJAV3pwbKiI7rCBX1ouOqKJzlJ>\n5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 h22sm1030609wmq.14 - gsmtp')
```

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import os.path

sender_email = "myemail@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "targetmail@outlook.com"
password = "mypassword"
SUBJECT = 'test email'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = sender_email
msg['To'] = receiver_email
msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
TEXT = 'This is my message'
msg.attach(MIMEText(TEXT, 'plain'))

file_location = 'test.xlsx'
filename = 'test.xlsx'

attachment = open(file_location, "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload(attachment.read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(sender_email,password)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, text)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either enable "Less secure apps" access (can't find the documentation link, google planned to turn this feature off eventually AFAIR) or use "App specific passwords" (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)

Comment: already have the 'Less Secure Apps' turned on, but it has not helped unfortunately.